# Android ListView: Align last list item to top of screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I have my listview's stackFromBottom XML attribute set to true, so that when the activity opens, the last items in the listview are the ones visible as opposed to the top items, as is the default.

However, I want the activity to open so that the last item in the listview is aligned to the top of the screen. In other words, there should be a blank space below this last item that takes up the remaining space.

I've attempted to do this by adding a footer view to the listview:

```
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, listview, false);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = footer.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = ???;
footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
listview.addFooterView(footer);
```

The problem is that I don't know during the activity's onCreate function what height to assign to the blank footer view. I need to know the height of the last item in the listview to decide what height to make the blank footer view, but the height of this last listview item is not a fixed number.

How can I get the height of that last listview item? Or perhaps there is a better way to do this altogether?

Comment: Does the empty view *have* to be a listview row? If not, it would be easier to add an empty view below the listview itself, with a layout_weight set so it will expand to whatever space is left.

Comment: The empty view does not have to be a listview row. The problem with having an empty view below the listview is that when I scroll, this empty space will always be there. I want to be able to scroll down (viewing the items above the last one in the listview) and have that empty space be filled by whatever listview items are being scrolled down the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very simple solution to this problem: just wrap your ListView in a FrameLayout. Apparently the alignment is handled differently than for other ViewGroups.

This is my working code:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Another approach would be to remove android:stackFromBottom and do the scrolling manually to simulate the attribute's behaviour. This would save you the additional layer but I wouldn't recommend to add the extra complexity.